# Launch IE from metro app and send post data to the website

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, uri-scheme, data-uri-scheme

I want to launch a website in IE from my metro app. While launching the website post data also need to be send.

I tried using `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);`

I am facing two issues here. 
one, i am not able to send post data to the website. Second, the IE is taking only 50% of the screen. I want it to consume the entire screen.

How can i possibly do that?

Comment: I doubt telling a browser to send a POST request when it launches is possible; that would be a very weird and insecure thing for a browser to offer… Why don’t you send your request from within your app instead?

Comment: That is possible if am using a webview inside my app to launch the webpage

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, you possible do not Need the webview. A POST Request often answers with data - not text/html. You could use HTTPClient instead

Comment: How can I post data when launching a website?

Comment: You can only send a GET request with LaunchUriAsync.

Comment: Is there any way to make the IE consume the entire screen. I couldn't find that option.